# complex query to equivalent criteriabuilder query(EntityManager)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

My Query is this:

**query1 = select a.id from entity1 a where a.id in (:List1)

       and not exists (select ex2 from entity2 ex2 where ex2.assignedId = a.id)

union

select ex.assignedId from  entity2 ex ,entity3 pi

       where ex.entity3Id = pi.id and ex.assignedId in (:List1)

          and   ex.assignedTypeId = :assignedTypeId  and   pi.processStatus = :status

and not exists

(select ex1.assignedId from  entity2 ex1 , entity3 pi1

            where ex1.entity3Id = pi1.id  and   ex1.assignedId = ex.assignedId

                  and ex1.assignedTypeId = :assignedTypeId

                              and   pi1.processStatus <> :status);**

and while trying to execute query,

Query existingIds=em.createQuery(query1); //With all parameters set

throws NullPointerException in line 87 of org.hibernate.hql.ast.ParameterTranslationsImpl

completely checked all the braces and parameters. The equivalent conversion works in mysql.
Can someone assist me in converting the query with CriteriaBuilder, finding it difficult to make the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if [JPQL supports](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28613_01/apirefs.1211/e24396/ejb3_langref.html) union operation at all. Are you putting this as NamedQuery or you are creating on the fly (entityManager.createQuery()) ?

Comment: It's entityManager.createQuery() with                                                         **'Query fetchIds=em.createQuery(query1);    fetchIds.setParameter(list1, listValues);                           fetchIds.setParameter("assignTypeId", 15);
fetchIds.setParameter(status, 4);'**

Comment: As I said, the query being formed is wrong. Use joins instead of inner selects. Use OR conditions in the same where clause instead of Union operation. Please go through JPQL documentation that I have mentioned in the comment.

Comment: No I need to append the result set, that the reason why using union.